# Understanding RGB components in matplotlib cmaps

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib

This is a follow up to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18661406/1461850).

From the answer, matplotlib cmaps are defined like this:

```
cdict = {'red': ((0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
                 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),

    'green': ((0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
              (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),

    'blue': ((0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
             (1.0, 0.0, 0.0))}

my_cmap = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('my_colormap', cdict)
```

I am struggling to understand how the numbers relate to the colour transitions.

What do the 'rows' and 'columns' in each `cdict` entry do?

Should you imagine the red, green and blue `cdict` entries stacked on top of each another?

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap

Answer (score 0):

In [pylab_examples example code: custom_cmap.py](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html) has explained well. let me interpret for you, if I'm wrong please correct me.

The first column stands for location 'x', 2rd and 3rd columns stand for color scale.

Now consider your example. This is a case of discontinuities, means the second and third column is the same. cdict['green'] is saying that for
0 <= x <= 1,0 (first column), y (second and third columns) are 0 (no green) to 1 (full green), means full green at x = 0.0 to no green at x = 1.0. At position x = 1.0, full red + full green + full blue  = white.

```
cdict = {'red': ((0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
                 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),

        'green': ((0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
                  (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),

        'blue': ((0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
                 (1.0, 0.0, 0.0))}
```

If there are discontinuities, then it is a little more complicated.

Label the 3 elements in each row in the cdict entry for a given color as
(x, y0, y1).  Then for values of x between x[i] and x[i+1] the color
value is interpolated between y1[i] and y0[i+1].

Going back to the cookbook example, look at cdict['red']; because y0 !=
y1, it is saying that for x from 0 to 0.5, red increases from 0 to 1,
but then it jumps down, so that for x from 0.5 to 1, red increases from
0.7 to 1.  Green ramps from 0 to 1 as x goes from 0 to 0.5, then jumps
back to 0, and ramps back to 1 as x goes from 0.5 to 1.

```
row i:   x  y0  y1
                /
               /
row i+1: x  y0  y1
```

For example:

```
cdict = {'red': ((0.0, 1.0, 1.0), # y[1,3] to y[2,2] is full red from position of 0.0 to 1.0.
                 (0.5, 1.0, 0.0), 
                 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)), 

        'green': ((0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
                  (0.5, 0.0, 0.0), 
                  (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)), 

        'blue': ((0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
                 (0.5, 0.0, 1.0), 
                 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0))}
```

[image]